# Need terraform entry to change hostname of newly created EC2 instance - using 'remote-exec'

Tags: terraform

My goal is the put an entry into terraform plan to rename the instance with whatever environment I am writing for (ie dev/qa/staging/etc)

ie:

sm-<whatever_build_enviroment>-nodejs-1

The aim is to amend /etc/hosts file to reflect the new name - using the remote_exec function. My entry below uses variable that I have already specified earlier in the plan (ie password & naming convention)

```
"echo ${var.anspassword} | sudo -S -k echo sm-${var.namingenv}-nodejs-1 > /etc/hosts",
```

Looking for the correct line that will allow this to work.

Comment: You haven't explaiend what exactly is the problem with the current line, nor even specified operating system you are using and how do you run `remote-exec`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a cloud-init-compatible cloud provider and a Linux distribution image which has cloud-init installed (most official images and official-derived images do) then you can set the system hostname declaratively by passing a cloud-init configuration that uses [the Set Hostname module](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#set-hostname).

For example, if you are using AWS then you can set `user_data` in one of the various resource types that directly or indirectly start EC2 instances:

```
  user_data = <<-EOT
    #cloud-config
    ${yamlencode(
      hostname = "sm-${var.namingenv}-nodejs-1"
    )}
  EOT
```

This example uses [`yamlencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/yamlencode.html) to construct a YAML document for cloud-init to read. The special `#cloud-config` prefix tells cloud-init to interpret it as a configuration file rather than as a script to execute. Cloud-init's Set Hostname module will then process this and take actions to set the hostname, so you don't need to write out a specific shell command yourself.

You can find out more about this approach in the Terraform documentation section [Provisioners are a Last Resort](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/syntax.html#provisioners-are-a-last-resort), which includes a list of cloud platforms that support passing in arbitrary metadata like this to instances, and includes some information about how to set it in each platform's provider.

An additional advantage of using cloud-init for this *particular* use-case is that cloud-init will process the Set Hostname module very early on in the boot process, whereas the earliest a `remote-exec` provisioner can take an action is after the system is booted enough to have the SSH server running, which is often after a number of other services are already running and may have already made use of the original hostname.